# Given the generative model $P(A, B, C)$, would it be faster to learn $P(A,B,C,D)$, or compose $P(A, B, C)$ with $P(D \mid A,B,C)$?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, generative-model

If we have a neural network that learns the generative model for $P(A, B, C)$, the joint PDF of the random variables $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Now, we want to learn the generative model for $P(A, B, C, D)$.

Is there any theory that says learning $P(A,B,C$) and then composing it with $P(D \mid A,B,C)$ is faster than learning $P(A,B,C,D)$ from scratch?